# Create dynamic number of input elements with R/Shiny

Tags: r, dynamic, input, shiny

I'm writing a Shiny app for visualizing insurance benefit plans at my company. Here is what I'd like to happen:

- I'll have a `selectInput` or `sliderInput` where the user will choose the number of individuals on their medical plan
- A matching number of double sided sliders will appear (one for each member)
- They can then input their estimates for best/worst case medical expenses for each member on their plan
- I have code that will take those estimates and create side by side plots illustrating the forecast cost on the three plan offerings so they can decide which one is least expensive based on their estimates

Here's my current `ui.R` file with hard coded inputs, simulating a family of four:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Side by side comparison"),

  sidebarPanel(

    selectInput(inputId = "class", label = "Choose plan type:",
                list("Employee only" = "emp", "Employee and spouse" = "emp_spouse",
                     "Employee and child" = "emp_child", "Employee and family" = "emp_fam")),

    sliderInput(inputId = "ind1", label = "Individual 1",
                min = 0, max = 20000, value = c(0, 2500), step = 250),

    sliderInput(inputId = "ind2", label = "Individual 2",
                min = 0, max = 20000, value = c(0, 2500), step = 250),

    sliderInput(inputId = "ind3", label = "Individual 3",
                min = 0, max = 20000, value = c(0, 2500), step = 250),

    sliderInput(inputId = "ind4", label = "Individual 4",
                min = 0, max = 20000, value = c(0, 2500), step = 250)
    ),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(  
    tabPanel("Side by Side", plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot", width = "100%")),
    tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput(outputId = "summary"))
  )
)))
```

Here's what it looks like (the transparent end sections are the result of HSA contributions from two of the plans. I thought it was a nice way to show both the premiums and medical expenses while showing the impact of the company HSA contribution. Thus, you'd just compare the length of the solid colors).

[image: shiny-example]

I've seen examples [like this](https://gist.github.com/wch/4211337) where the UI input itself is fixed (in this case, one `checkboxGroupInput` exists, but its contents are tailored based on the choice from another UI input), but I've not seen examples of tailoring *the number* (or, say, type) of input elements spawned as the result of another UI input's contents.

Any suggestions on this (is it even possible)?

---

My last resort will be to create, say, 15 input sliders and initialize them to zero. My code will work just fine, but I'd like to clean up the interface by not having to create that many sliders just for the occasional user who has a very large family.

---

**Update based on Kevin Ushay's answer**

I tried to go the `server.R` route and have this:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    members <- as.integer(input$members) # default 2
    max_pred <- as.integer(input$max_pred) # default 5000
    lapply(1:members, function(i) {
      sliderInput(inputId = paste0("ind", i), label = paste("Individual", i),
                  min = 0, max = max_pred, value = c(0, 500), step = 100)
    })

  })

})
```

Immediately afterwards, I try and extract the values out of `input` for each individual's expenses:

```
expenses <- reactive({
    members <- as.numeric(input$members)

    mins <- sapply(1:members, function(i) {
      as.numeric(input[[paste0("ind", i)]])[1]
    })

    maxs <- sapply(1:members, function(i) {
      as.numeric(input[[paste0("ind", i)]])[2]
    })

    expenses <- as.data.frame(cbind(mins, maxs))
})
```

Lastly, I have two functions that create objects to store a data frame for plotting based on the low and high medical expense estimates. They're called `best_case` and `worst_case` and both need the `expenses` object to work, so I call it as my first line as I learned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683933/set-global-object-in-shiny)

```
best_case <- reactive({

    expenses <- expenses()

    ...

)}
```

I got some errors, so I used `browser()` to step through the `expenses` bit and noticed peculiar things like `input$ind1` not seeming to exist from within the `expenses` function.

I also played around with various `print()` statements in it to see what was happening. The most striking is when I do `print(names(input))` as the very first line in the function:

```
[1] "class"    "max_pred" "members" 

[1] "class"    "ind1"     "ind2"     "max_pred" "members"
```

I get *two* outputs, which I believe is due to the defining of `expenses` and subsequent calling of it. Strangely... I don't get a third when `worst_case` uses the exact same `expenses <- expense()` line.

If I do something like `print(expenses)` inside of my `expenses` function, I also get duplicates:

```
# the first
  mins maxs
1   NA   NA
2   NA   NA

# the second
  mins maxs
1    0  500
2    0  500
```

Any tips on why my `input` elements for `ind1` and `ind2` wouldn't show up until `expenses` is called the second time and thus prevent the data frame from being created correctly?

Comment: You can use `do.call(sidebarPanel, inputs)`, where `inputs` is a list of `sliderInput` objects. The list could in turn be generated by `lapply(1:4, function(i), sliderInput(inputId = paste0("ind", i), label = paste("Individual", i), min = 0, max = 20000, value = c(0, 2500), step = 250),`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Liking this (hadn't thought of `do.call`!)... would you care to show a brief example? Would I pre-populate `inputs` with a list of, say, 15 of these and then do something like `do.call(sliderbarPanel, inputs[1:n])` based on their # of members (calling it `n`)? Still not clear on dynamically naming them or extracting only the number I want from the list.

Comment: You commented while I was commenting. That's what I was looking for, and I'll give that a whirl and get back to you. Feel free to write that brief example up and I'd be happy to accept, assuming it works :) Looks very promising and about exactly like the sort of thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 54):

You could handle generation of the UI element in `server.R`, so you have something like:

```
ui.R
----

shinyUI( pageWithSideBar(
    ...
    selectInput("numIndividuals", ...)
    uiOutput("sliders"),
    ...
))
```

and

```
server.R
--------

shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    numIndividuals <- as.integer(input$numIndividuals)
    lapply(1:numIndividuals, function(i) {
      sliderInput(...)
    })
  })


})
```

When I have UI elements that depend on values from other UI elements, I find it easiest to generate them in `server.R`.

It's useful to understand that all of the `_Input` functions *just generate HTML*. When you want to generate that HTML *dynamically* it makes sense to move it to `server.R`. And perhaps the other thing worth emphasizing is that it's okay to return a `list` of HTML 'elements' in a `renderUI` call.

Comment: I liked the idea of putting it in `server.R`, so I did. From the UI side, everything seemed to work great until I then wrote code to actually extract the values. I edited my answer to explain the result. Would you care to take a look at the issues I'm encountering? Many thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Kevin, if you add a bit about checking for the dynamically created inputs being `NULL`, I'd like to accept this answer as I prefer how it's living in shiny server as sort of a programmatic choice. For more understanding on the `NULL` check, see [mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/OMAW1fraHUs). The object `input$dynamic-name` doesn't exist on the first go around, so if you try to do something like `lapply()` with it, you get an error because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Can I ask you to edit my answer? I'm not exactly sure where the `NULL` check should go. Do you mean something like `if (!(is.null(input$numIndividuals))) { ... } else { return(NULL) }` ?

Comment: Alternatively, it's entirely acceptable to write your own answer (take the parts of mine that got you started) and accept it as correct.

Comment: Ha! Didn't think of that. I still think my real code is a mess and that I'm not grasping the intricacies of reactive inputs, but it now works thanks to your post and the mailing list. I think it runs pretty slow, as one has to do `if(is.null(input$obj)) { } else { }` lines in pretty much anything that might cause an error if `input$obj` doesn't exist yet (which it doesn't on the first run through).

Comment: Thanks for emphasising that all `Input` functions generate HTML code.

Answer (score 27):

You can access dynamically named variables from shiny using this syntax:

```
input[["dynamically_named_element"]]
```

So in your example above, if you initialise your slider elements as so

```
# server.R

output$sliders <- renderUI({
  members <- as.integer(input$members) # default 2
  max_pred <- as.integer(input$max_pred) # default 5000
  lapply(1:members, function(i) {
    sliderInput(inputId = paste0("ind", i), label = paste("Individual", i),
                min = 0, max = max_pred, value = c(0, 500), step = 100)
  })
})

# ui.R

selectInput("num", "select number of inputs", choices = seq(1,10,1))
uiOutput("input_ui")
```

You can print the values to a table using the following

```
# server.R

output$table <- renderTable({
    num <- as.integer(input$num)

    data.frame(lapply(1:num, function(i) {
      input[[paste0("ind", i)]]
    }))
  })

# ui.R

tableOutput("table")
```

See [here](https://polyphant.shinyapps.io/dynamic_ui) for a working Shiny example. Working gist [here](https://gist.github.com/christopherlovell/b7ecdf8b0aa82c20fa46).

Source: Joe Cheng's first answer, about half way down [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/YAboU6gxrEw)

Comment: Any direction on saving the values as a vector instead of a data.frame?

Comment: @JeffParker perhaps this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070173/convert-data-frame-column-to-a-vector

Comment: `sapply(1:num, function(i) {
      input[[paste0("ind", i)]]
    })` did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

You could generate the sidebar with `do.call` and `lapply`, something like:

```
# create the first input, which isn't dynamic
sel.input = selectInput(inputId = "class", label = "Choose plan type:",
            list("Employee only" = "emp", "Employee and spouse" = "emp_spouse",
                 "Employee and child" = "emp_child", "Employee and family" = "emp_fam"))

num.individuals = 5  # determine the number of individuals here

# concatenate the select input and the other inputs
inputs = c(list(sel.input), lapply(1:num.individuals, function(i) {
    sliderInput(inputId = paste0("ind", i), label = paste("Individual", i), min = 0, max = 20000, value = c(0, 2500), step = 250)
}))

sidebar.panel = do.call(sidebarPanel, inputs)
```

Comment: I essentially used this idea, but put it in `server.R` like Kevin suggested above. Unfortunately, I'm having issues actually accessing the values stored in the result. I edited my answer to elaborate.

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160372/r-shiny-how-to-build-dynamic-ui-text-input. That approach doesn't require knowing input$numIndividuals in advance, and moreover, you can save the previous inputs.