# Displaying drop downs dynamically in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am not familiar to working on Shiny but I want to build an application in which I ask the user to enter a number in a text box and then accordingly display drop downs. The items in all the drop downs will be the same. For example, I am reading value from a csv file

```
    Name  Designation   Gender
    Tom     CEO          M
    JIM     CSO          M
    RACHEL  SECRETARY    F
    ARYA    SECRETARY    M
```

If I enter 12 in my text box, I should get 12 drop downs with each drop down having 3 elements(the distinct designations) i.e CEO,CSO and SECRETARY. I want to use these 12 selections further so I would like to store them if possible. If this is doable in shiny please post the server.R and ui.R code. Thanks.

Comment: I think what would be helpful is if you actually built a small working app and post it for further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I based the code below on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160372/r-shiny-how-to-build-dynamic-ui-text-input).  I think it does what you are asking.  Simply save it as app.R in RStudio and you can launch it from the toolbar at the top. A good place to start when learning about dynamic UI elements in Shiny is found [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html).

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$input_ui <- renderUI({
    num <- as.integer(input$num)

    lapply(1:num, function(i) {
      selectInput(paste0("n_input_", i), label = paste0("n_input", i),  
                  choices = list("CEO" = 1, "CSO" = 2, "SECRETARY" = 3), 
                  selected = 1)
    })
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    num <- as.integer(input$num)

    data.frame(lapply(1:num, function(i) {
      input[[paste0("n_input_", i)]]
    }))
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("num", label = h3("Numeric input"), value = 1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("input_ui"),
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As is shown in the screenshot below the output is currently numerical with:

```
"CEO" = 1
"CSO" = 2
"SECRETARY" = 3
```

[image: Screenshot of Shiny App]

Comment: I just hosted my first shiny app. The link and the code have been helpful. many many thanks.