# Number of Conditional panels depending on sliderInput

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

In my R shiny app I have a `sliderInput`:

```
sliderInput("number","Specify number :",min   = 1,max   = 10,value = 2,step  = 1)
```

I want to give some more inputs. The number of these inputs should be equal to the value of `sliderInput` (for each number less or equal to the sliderInput there should be another input option or a text message). This results in a number of `conditionalPanels`.
Of course, I can define 10 different `conditionalPanels`, but I am looking for a loop or something. I tried `lapply`:

```
lapply(1:10,function(i){condition='number>=i',helptext('test-should depend on i')})
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. How can I define the condition depending on the sliderinput?

Comment: If `input$number` is 3, then we want 3 more textInput to show up?

Comment: Yeah correct. TextInput was just an example, I want to have numericInputs, but I think this doens't change the question

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130455) not what you need? (I didn't test the solutions.)

Comment: That is great yes!  I solved the problem :) I put the other inputs in the server.R part as a render object and then it worked by calling it with output. Actually, I don't understand why my approach with lapply in UI.R doesn't work. But at least now I know how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create dynamic number of input elements with R/Shiny](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130455/create-dynamic-number-of-input-elements-with-r-shiny)