# Make object created inside one reactive object available to another in shiny

Tags: r, output, rstudio, shiny

I have a shiny app in which I define an object based on sliders and create a `data.frame` from it. This gets used to create a plot, below which I'd like to include a summary table. My issue is that the plot must be defined inside of a reactive object to update based on the sliders, but I found that when I tried to access the object to print a summary inside of a *different* reactive object, it wasn't found.

I'd like to not run through the same calculation code twice just to get the object into the other reactive object. My two initial ideas:

- I tried using `save(object, file = "...")` inside the first reactive object and then putting `load(file = "...")` inside the second, but it doesn't update.
- I thought of defining my object outside of my reactive `plotOutput` definition, but I'm pretty sure it won't update when user inputs are changed; it will just stay with the value of the initial `input` object default settings.

Well, just went ahead and tried the latter idea, and it doesn't even get that far:

- I put it before `shinyServer(...)` and it can't generate the data because my call depends on `input` and it doesn't know about `input` at that point.
- I put it after `shinyServer(...)` but before `renderPlot(...)` to try and make sort of a "globally available" object for all output objects, and it scolding me for trying to do something that uses `input` outside of a reactive function.

Here's an example to illustrate, modified from Shiny's ["Hello Shiny!" example](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#hello-shiny):

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that plots random distributions 
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("obs", 
                "Number of observations:", 
                min = 1,
                max = 1000, 
                value = 500)
  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot"),
    tableOutput("summary")
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to generate and plot a random distribution
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate an rnorm distribution and plot it
    dist <- rnorm(input$obs)
    hist(dist)
  })

  output$summary <- renderTable({
    #dist <- rnorm(input$obs)
    summary <- table(data.frame(cut(dist, 10)))
  })
})
```

If you run it as is, `cut` will throw and error because it doesn't know about `dist`. If you uncomment the line where we re-define `dist` as is done in `plotOutput`, then it will work.

This is simple code -- mine is quite a bit more involved and I'd really prefer not to run it twice just to make the same result known to another reactive output.

Suggestions?

Comment: Voting to close. After I asked my question, I tried searching with better terminology (calling what I'm doing looking for a "global object" vs. my layman phrase above), and found what I consider a duplicate which answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

Just to flesh out the example above based on the answer in the [other question I consider mine to have duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683933/set-global-object-in-shiny), the code would look like this:

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to generate and plot a random distribution
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dist <- reactive(rnorm(input$obs))

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate an rnorm distribution and plot it
    dist <- dist()
    hist(dist)
  })

  output$summary <- renderTable({
    dist <- dist()
    summary <- table(data.frame(cut(dist, 10)))
  })
})
```