# shiny flexdashboard: reference object in new tabset

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a flexdashboard with one column and two tabsets. I want to create and plot `dat2` in one tabset, and then show the data for `dat2` in a second tabset. The real use case is more complex and I don't have it setup to run from global (maybe I need to figure out how to do that).

The following results in an error that `dat2` cannot be located.

````
---
title: "test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: bootstrap
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r global, include=FALSE}
  set.seed(1)
  dat <- data.frame(age = sample(15:99, 100, replace=TRUE),
                    y = runif(100))
```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

```{r}
# age
  sliderInput("agerange", label = "Age", 
              min = 15, 
              max = 99, 
              value = c(15, 99),
              step=10)
```

Page 1
=====================================

Column {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Plot

```{r}
renderPlot({
  dat2 <- 
  dat %>%
    filter(age >= input$agerange[1] & age <= input$agerange[2]) %>%
    mutate(y2 = y*2)

  ggplot(dat2, aes(y2)) +
    geom_histogram()
})
```


Column {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Table

```{r}
  DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(dat2, options = list(bPaginate = FALSE))
  })
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work (based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19466838/841405)). Simpler fixes out there, or is the basic approach to do munging in reactives, assign to an `object` inside the reactive, and then reassign that object in a `render` function (e.g., `object <- object()`)?

````
---
title: "test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: bootstrap
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r global, include=FALSE}
  set.seed(1)
  dat <- data.frame(age = sample(15:99, 100, replace=TRUE),
                    y = runif(100))
```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

```{r}
# age
  sliderInput("agerange", label = "Age", 
              min = 15, 
              max = 99, 
              value = c(15, 99),
              step=10)
```

Page 1
=====================================

Column {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Plot

```{r}
  dat2 <- reactive(
    dat %>%
    filter(age >= input$agerange[1] & age <= input$agerange[2]) %>%
    mutate(y2 = y*2)
  )

renderPlot({
  dat2 <- dat2()

  ggplot(dat2, aes(y2)) +
    geom_histogram()
})
```


Column {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Table

```{r}
  DT::renderDataTable({
    dat2 <- dat2()
    DT::datatable(dat2, options = list(bPaginate = FALSE))
  })
```
````